# How can I smooth a creaky voice?

Tags: audio-restoration

I recorded a girl who had a small physical problem and very often, too often, her voice breaks up into "vocal fry" or creakiness.  Is there some software that can restore smoothness, interpolating from one cycle to another just a few cycles away? I know this is very fine work and most of the software I have tried needs too big a brush.
          Thanks,

```
               Judy
```

Comment: Thanks to all who answered this question.  I was trying out some of the ideas and I hit on something that makes it all so much easier.  I had been thinking that the high peaks were the good part and needed to be copied into the low parts, but it is the other way around.  The low parts are the good parts and the peaks are like voice pops.  I started deleting the spike cycles and what was left is the real vowel, which then can be treated with all your good ideas.  Thanks!  - Judy

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, no not really. You're best bet is layering multiple samples together. If you only have, and can only get the one sample, you might try creating your own multiple versions with extremely slight offsets few milliseconds and a harmonizer or similar to +- a few cents on each track not the original. I don't know how well that will really work but it's the best guess I have besides a plain no.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a multiple sample approach, edit with fine detail to fill gaps.
Micha's idea is good,

but to fill in small gaps, like a breaking voice, I'd say a finely tuned Reverb with a lot of feedback on a copy of the voice, then cut out and replace the bits you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, more time consuming;

depending on how large these gaps are, you could fill them with a reversed section from a few milliseconds before.

I don't think there's a quick fix. Maybe something from iZotope's Restoration range?

Answer (score -1):

try a compressor, flanger, love philter, free filter or vocoder...

try a soft knee on the compressor

i'm thinking a limiter would work, which can be automated to control gain, envelope (ADSR) and the noise gate. some of them have saturation as well as soft knee compression built in. you can literally turn the knobs as the recording light is on and playing through the song without playing any notes, it will record the knobs you turn and do that in the .wav or whatever you export it as. there's one in FL Studio, here's a pic http://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/img_plug/plugin_fx_fruitylimitercomp.jpg

Comment: If there were an effect that could clean up rough vocals like the OP describes, it would be the single most popular studio effect ever created, and we would all know instantly what it is because it would be so famous. The best that could be done is Micah's suggestion of double-tracking it (artificially or naturally) to try to cover up the rasp.